# How to fix Error NU1202 Package Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, version, nuget-package

I'm building a Xamarin App!

When I install  `Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs`  Nuget package it shows me this error and no other nuget package is updating even !

I tried everything searched on google but still I've no idea what to do with this error

**Error:**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0103  The name 'Detail' does not exist in the current
>   context   DummyApp    C:\Users\hashir.malik\source\repos\DummyApp\DummyApp\DummyApp\MainPage.xaml.cs  29  Active
>   Error NU1202  Package Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs 27.0.2 is not
>   compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs 27.0.2 supports: monoandroid81
>   (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)    DummyApp    C:\Users\hashir.malik\source\repos\DummyApp\DummyApp\DummyApp\DummyApp.csproj   1

**ScreenShot** : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaLBj.png

Comment: any update on the question? Does it work now or not?

Answer (score 12):

You're trying to install the package to the shared project which is .Net Standard 2.0.

The Packages only need to be installed to the Android project. So uncheck "DummyApp" and only check "DummyApp.Android" in NuGet UI.

[image]